# MBProgressHUD hide after receive response from server

Tags: iphone, ios, xmlhttprequest, mbprogresshud

i want to hide MBProgressHUD when i'm receive xml response from server and i use httpconnection to get xml from server,,anybody help me?? thx before..

Answer (score 2):

follow this steps to hide the ProgressHUD

take a class level variable for hud

```
MBProgressHUD *hud;
```

then make two functions

```
-(void)showProgress
{
if (!hud)
    hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];

    [self.view addSubview:hud];
    //hud.delegate = self;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading...";
    [hud show:YES];
}
-(void)hideProgress
{
    [hud hide:YES];
    [hud removeFromSuperview];
    [hud release];
    hud=nil;
}
```

call showProgress() when you initiate the network hit
and call hideProgress() when callback of success or failure called.

Answer (score 0):

You should retain an instance of MBProgressHUD in the class or the delegate that is getting the data from the server,

in the interface

```
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud;
}
```

- do [hud show..] when the progress starts and
- [hud hide] when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you  use HUD delgete for hideen

try this:-

```
-(void)hudWasHidden          // for remove the hud
{
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];
```

}

call the Hud

```
HUD         = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
            HUD.graceTime     = .1;
            HUD.navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
            HUD.labelFont     = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
            HUD.delegate      = self;
            [self.view addSubview:HUD];
            [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(yourFunction name:) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

in .h File use this

MBProgressHUD             *HUD;